# Return multiple rows from conditional group by without union

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to build a query which supports conditional group by in SQLite DB.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT 
      case 
       when A>1 AND B>1 THEN 1
       when X>1 AND Y>1 THEN 2
       when C>1 AND D>1 THEN 3
      END AS data_grp,
     SUM(col1) AS col1,
     SUM(col2) AS col2
FROM tbl
GROUP BY data_grp;
```

This Works pretty fine if only single case is true at a time. if multiple cases are true in a row then it returns the first case instead of all satisfying groups.

I have tried this by the `union` which works well but very slow.  Is there any other way to fetch results fast with this conditional group.

**Sample Data & Expected results:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  tbl;
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
    A INT,
    B INT,
    C INT,
    D INT,
    X INT,
    Y INT,
    col1 int,
    col2 int

);

INSERT INTO tbl(A,B,C,D,X,Y,col1,col2) values (2,3,0,0,0,0,5,10);
INSERT INTO tbl(A,B,C,D,X,Y,col1,col2) values (0,0,0,0,8,10,3,2);
INSERT INTO tbl(A,B,C,D,X,Y,col1,col2) values (5,4,4,9,0,0,3,2);

    SELECT 
          case 
           when A>1 AND B>1 THEN 1
           when X>1 AND Y>1 THEN 2
           when C>1 AND D>1 THEN 3
          END AS data_grp,
         SUM(col1) AS col1,
         SUM(col2) AS col2
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY data_grp;
```

**Query  Output  :**

```
"1" "8" "12"
"2" "3" "2"
```

**Expected Output :**

```
"1" "8" "12"
"2" "3" "2"
"3" "3" "2"
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful here.

Comment: @sgeddes Added sample data.please check.

Comment: using `union` seems the best approach here

Comment: In actual scenario, I have more than 100 cases and using Union would not be beneficial as union are limited to 64 per query in SQLite. Also, In this case, union works very slow because of the sequential processing.

Comment: There is no limit of 64 compound queries. Anyway, show your UNION query; it's likely that it can be optimized.

Comment: Okay, If there is no limit but sequential nature of union cannot be resolved. Using more than 100 union queries will result in slow performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `GROUP BY` directly because of the overlapping groups.
You can use something like following, although this may also be slow.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(x) AS (
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT x+1 FROM cnt
      LIMIT 3
  )
SELECT x as data_grp, sum(col1), sum(col2)
FROM cnt, 
      (SELECT 
          case when A>1 AND B>1 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END as dg1,
          case when X>1 AND Y>1 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END as dg2,
          case when C>1 AND D>1 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END as dg3,
          col1, col2
        FROM tbl) t WHERE x=dg1 or x=dg2 or x=dg3
GROUP BY x
```

Comment: This solution looks good to me. This can be improved more if the data of recursive CTE put into a temporary table with an index on column `x`. So, subsequent join condition(where clause) will execute fastly.

Answer (score 1):

I am wary of summarizing data, where the result is on multiple rows and the totals don't match the original data.  Of course, sometimes it is necessary, but here are two alternatives.

If you can be slightly flexible in your results, then you can concat the conditions together to get a more complex group:

```
SELECT ( (CASE WHEN A > 1 AND B > 1 THEN '1' ELSE '' END) ||
         (CASE WHEN X > 1 AND Y > 1 THEN '2' ELSE '' END) ||
         (CASE WHEN C > 1 AND D > 1 THEN '3' ELSE '' END)
       ) AS data_grp,
       SUM(col1) AS col1, SUM(col2) AS col2
FROM tbl
GROUP BY data_grp;
```

I would actually write this as:

```
SELECT ( (CASE WHEN A > 1 AND B > 1 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) ||
         (CASE WHEN X > 1 AND Y > 1 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) ||
         (CASE WHEN C > 1 AND D > 1 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)
       ) AS data_grp,
```

So `data_grp` gets a string of 0's and 1's indicating the group.

These results are *not* the same as your results.  They are more what I would want, if I were looking at different groups -- I would want to see the overlaps between the groups.

Or, I would put the values in separate columns:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN A > 1 AND B > 1 THEN col1 ELSE 0 END) as sum1_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN X > 1 AND Y > 1 THEN col1 ELSE 0 END) as sum1_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN C > 1 AND D > 1 THEN col1 ELSE 0 END) as sum1_3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A > 1 AND B > 1 THEN col2 ELSE 0 END) as sum2_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN X > 1 AND Y > 1 THEN col2 ELSE 0 END) as sum2_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN C > 1 AND D > 1 THEN col2 ELSE 0 END) as sum2_3
FROM tbl;
```

These are the same results, but pivoted differently.